# Grab image data from URL via proxy and convert to base64

Tags: image, url, groovy, proxy

I've got a question related to grabbing an image from a URL via proxy and converting it to base64.

Is there a simple way of doing this like the below jsoup method?

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("myproxyurl", 8080))
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("mytargeturl").proxy(proxy).get()
Elements headline = doc?.getElementsByClass("myHTMLclass")
```

I am looking to do this in Groovy/Java (preferably Groovy).

So far I got here:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("myproxy", 8080))
URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&markers=size:large%7Ccolor:yellow%7Clabel:A%7CNew%20York")
def image = url.openConnection(proxy).getContent()

println(image)
```

But I'm getting `sun.awt.image.URLImageSource@26d9b808` as an output in the console

Can anyone help? The image in question is this one:

[image: New York Static Goole Maps Image]

Just to be clear, I want to grab the above image (actual image) from the above-mentioned URL and convert it to base64 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
// By default this won't use a proxy, but if you pass one in, it will!
String toBase64(URL url, Proxy proxy = Proxy.NO_PROXY) {
   url.openConnection(proxy).inputStream.withCloseable {
       it.bytes.encodeBase64()
   }
}

URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&markers=size:large%7Ccolor:yellow%7Clabel:A%7CNew%20York")

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("myproxyurl", 8080));

String encoded = toBase64(url, proxy)
```

Comment: Made it into a one-liner and it seems to be working:
`def encodedImage = mapUrl.openConnection(myProxy).inputStream.withCloseable { it.bytes.encodeBase64() }`

Comment: fun until you need it again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about proxy settings, but if you want to convert image into base64 with java, so that you can do with below code.

```
public class ChangeBase {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String encodstring = encodeFileToBase64("http://imageurl");
    System.out.println(encodstring);

}

private static byte[] getByteFromImage(String urlStr) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    return data.getData();
}

private static String encodeFileToBase64(String url) {
    String encodedString = null;
    try {
        byte[] bytes = getByteFromImage(url);
        encodedString = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes), "UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encodedString;
}
}
```

Note: I used above code for image stored in my drive, same thing you can try with image from url, suggested one is create byte to file from url and pass same to **encodeFiletoBase64** method, don't save file locally on system.

Comment: Follow the edit code for getByte and convert to Base64 directly from URL.

Comment: Thanks @Simmant, but is there like a one liner for this thing? I have something similar that spans multiple lines. I'm just trying to get things much simpler than this low level stuff.